# Check if the right versions of Flex and Bison are installed

Tags: bash, unix, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing a BASH installer script for a program the requires Flex and Bison version 2.5 or higher.

I've already got the code to check that `flex` and `bison` are installed at all.

I'm not sure if this has stayed constant throughout the versions but here are the outputs of `flex --version` and `bison --version` respectively:

```
➜  ~  flex --version
flex 2.5.35
➜  ~  bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 2.5
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.

Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is there a "right" way to check to make sure that the system has flex and bison 2.5 *or higher*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since bash doesn't handle floating point numbers, you can do the actual comparison in awk.

```
for cmd in flex bison; do
   [[ $("$cmd" --version) =~ ([0-9][.][0-9.]*) ]] && version="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
   if ! awk -v ver="$version" 'BEGIN { if (ver < 2.5) exit 1; }'; then
      printf 'ERROR: %s version 2.5 or higher required\n' "$cmd"
   fi
done
```

In order to get this to work in pure bash, each number needs to be compared individually:

```
req_version=(2 5)
for cmd in flex bison; do
   [[ $("$cmd" --version) =~ ([0-9][.][0-9.]*) ]] && IFS=. read -ra version <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

   for (( i=0; i < "${#req_version[@]}"; i++)); do
      if (( "${req_version[i]}" > "${version[i]}" )); then
         printf 'ERROR: %s version 2.5 or higher required\n' "$cmd"
         exit 1
      fi
   done
done
```

Comment: On Mac OS X, I'm getting an "invalid -v option" when trying to use the `awk` variation—do you know why that would be?

Comment: Perhaps the Mac OS X version of awk is not POSIX compliant. The -v option is defined by POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/awk.html

Comment: @AaronYodaiken - I made a change to the awk command in the answer. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using [autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system). Then you will have predefined macros to test for the presence of [flex](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_flex.html#ax_prog_flex) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_bison.html#ax_prog_bison):

```
AX_PROG_FLEX(ACTION-IF-TRUE,ACTION-IF-FALSE)
AX_PROG_BISON(ACTION-IF-TRUE,ACTION-IF-FALSE)
```

Unluckily it seems you cannot test for a given version. But the m4 macros responsible for testing for the presence of bison and flex are very short, so you may easily modify them. You may get some inspiration on how to do that by having a look at the [way autotools look for a given version of C++ Boost library](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_base.html#ax_boost_base). Actually, if you come up with a modification for including version testing for flex and bison in autotools, you may consider contributing your solution :)

You will also get many other benefits by using autotools. Specifically, you will be using a highly tested and portable environment for building and installing applications.

If you prefer to do a custom bash installing tool, then I would say using `--version` and parsing the result (by using a regular expression, for instance) is already an appropriate way to do so. Most (if not all) GNU applications support since long time ago the `--version` command as the standard way to check for the actual program version.

Comment: I was about to post a bash solution, but using a build system such as autotools is likely the correct way.

Comment: This program actually is only a portion in C, it's actually not very very platform specific, and I need the BASH script to interface with a standard installer format. But I agree—in most cases, using autotools would the way to go. @jordanm, could you please post your solution?

Comment: @AaronYodaiken - Solution posted

Answer (score 0):

If you have two version numbers extracted, you can compare them with a script such as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
#   Compare two version numbers:
#   Exit status 0 equal; 1 if first is larger, 2 if second is larger.

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 ver1 ver2\n" if (scalar(@ARGV) != 2);

my @v1 = split /[._-]/, $ARGV[0];
my @v2 = split /[._-]/, $ARGV[1];
my $n1 = scalar(@v1);
my $n2 = scalar(@v2);

my $n = $n1 < $n2 ? $n1 : $n2;

my $rc = 0;

for (my $i = 0; $i < $n && $rc == 0; $i++)
{
    $rc = 1 if ($v1[$i] > $v2[$i]);
    $rc = 2 if ($v2[$i] > $v1[$i]);
}

if ($rc == 0 && $n1 != $n2)
{
    $rc = ($n1 > $n2) ? 1 : 2;
}

exit $rc;
```

#### Examples of use

```
$ vercmp 2.3.5 2.3.5; echo $?
0
$ vercmp 2.3.35 2.3.5; echo $?
1
$ vercmp 2.5.35 2.3.5; echo $?
1
$ vercmp 2.5.35 2.6.5; echo $?
2
$
```

It manages to deal with an awful lot of weird version number comparisons, but probably not everything.  You could design it so that it echoes the status (0, 1, 2) instead of exiting with the different statuses.

There are also numerous 'version' modules available at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=version&mode=all).